# Faster way to match id's in text files and retrieve corresponding value

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have two text files, the simplified version of the first one looks like this:

[image]

The first field (letter) is an unique value, the second field (number) is not unique. The file has 7 rows, the real file has more than a million rows. The second file looks like this:

[image]

It has one field and like the first file it's unique. All the values that you have in the second file are in the first file but not vice versa. So the second file has less entries. It also doesn't have the second field (number)!

My question is: What is the fastest way to match the values from the second file against the first and find the corresponding number? So my goal is to get this:

[image]

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
with open("file_2") as f2:  
    for l in f2:
        with open("file_1") as f1:
            for line in f1:
                if l["letter"] == line["letter"]:
                    print(line["number"])
```

But this approach will take several days, is there a faster way? I've read about sets but that's used to check if the letter is in the file, then I can't retrieve the number.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: use a `dict` or `pandas`

Comment: Read the second file into a `set`, then loop over the first file and output the rows where the first column is in the set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you read file_1 several times(it is row count of file_2)

I think you'd better read file_1 just once.

And filtering data of file_1 with keys(letter) in file_2

```
def parse(line):
  # DO SOMETHING
  return (letter, number)
def getletter(line):
  # DO SOMETHING
  return letter

with open("file_2") as f2:
  letters = map(getletter, f2.readlines)
  with open("file_1") as f1:
    letter_number = map(parse, f1.readlines)
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in letters, letter_number))
    # result is (letter, number) entries
```